# Numba module is empty in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, python-import, numba

I wanted to use Numba to run my python code on the GPU so I installed Anaconda, last version (4.6.12 with Python 3.7). I tried to load the function vectorize from numba:

```py
from numba import vectorize
```

But I got the error code:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'vectorize' from 'numba'
```

The module is installed, I don't get errors when I import it, but when I use the `dir(numba)` command like so:

```py
import numba

print(dir(numba))
```

I get this :

```
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'numba']
```

I tried to reinstall the module using the command `conda install numba --force-reinstall` but I still get the error.

Comment: Do you have a file called `numba.py` in that directory?

Comment: Yes the name of the file is numba.py. Oh. I think I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pythons `import` looks at different locations for matching modules. The (very simplified) order is (1) built-in C-modules (e.g. `sys`) (2) current directory (3) built-in modules and installed packages <sup>1</sup>.

What is relevant in your case is that Python found a `numba` module (your `numba.py` <sup>2</sup>) in the current directory it didn't look for an installed `numba` module. So it should be sufficient to rename the `numba.py` file to something else, e.g. `my_numba.py` (and remove the corresponding file from the `__pycache__` directory).

In general if you suspect that you imported the wrong module, you can always check the `__file__` attribute (most modules have it) and check if it's the expected path:

```
import numba
print(numba.__file__)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> It's actually a lot more complicated and one can also customize a lot of it, but that's actually not relevant here.

<sup>2</sup> Yes, you can import the current module in itself - but it's generally not advised...